# AJAX Form submit with save password from browser and no "Confirm form submission" request if I reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm doing a simple login form on my site. Here is the situation:

- If I do a pure Jquery AJAX form submission and then redirect (in the JS
  code), the browser doesn't offer to save the info (ie username and
  password).
- If I do a normal form submit, when I land on the next page and I do
  back or refresh, I get that very irritating and annoying "Confirm
  form submission".

**My question is, it possible to get the best of both worlds? If yes, how?**

To be clear, I want to do a form submit, preferably using AJAX so that if there is an error, I don't have to reload the page and just display the error, I want the browser to offer the possibility of saving the information and I don't want the "confirm form submission" on the page I redirect.

*I thought of adding a page in the middle, so submit to a blank page that just redirects to the page I want to go. But once you are there, if you hit back, you are redirected to the same page, so you have click back 2 times. Is that how other people do it?*

Thanks for your help.

PS: I've seen all these posts...

- [Ajax login form - browsers won't save password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196846/ajax-login-form-browsers-wont-save-password)
- [How to make Chrome remember password for an AJAX form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430129/how-to-make-chrome-remember-password-for-an-ajax-form)
- [How can I get browser to prompt to save password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password)
- [Why won't this form prompt the browser to offer to save password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294657/why-wont-this-form-prompt-the-browser-to-offer-to-save-password)

PPS: Seems like the submit to iframe no longer works in modern browsers.

Comment: Use [history.forward()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_forward.asp) on login page.

Comment: Maybe, use AJAX for form validation and displaying errors, and the old-fashion POST refresh form for login logic ?

Comment: @RadoslavGeorgiev - Thanks, but that won't solve the "confirm form submission" issue.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need a well-formed HTML form element, with method and action, and a `submit` button as well, like this one:

```
<form method="post" action="login.xxx" onsubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="text" id="username" />
  <input type="password" id="password" />

  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

After that, handle everything into the `validate` javascript method, preventing your form post (that will work on a non-javascript environment anyway) and using ajax instead:

```
function validate() {
  // Ajax request using gathered form data, followed by a redirect to the logged-in page

  return false; // To prevent form submission
}
```

This way, your login info should be saved. For the "Confirm form submission" message, it will not appear since you'll do an javascript redirect if login info is okay.